# numpy/scipy tricky extraction of block matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a very large unitary matrix (15625 x 15625), with a fairly simple block-diagonal structure: it alternates identity matrices with non-trivial ones. All of these blocks have varying size, so I can't predict where exactly the non-trivial matrices are.

I would like to extract all the non-trivial submatrices in an array, together with another array of integers telling me how large are the identity matrices occurring in between.

I suspect that since the sizes are unpredictable, I have to check whether a 1 in the diagonal corresponds to all zeros in its row and column (in which case it belongs to an identity matrix), then once I have pinpointed where the identity matrices are, I can take the remaining blocks. But I'm very new to Python, it's likely that I'm missing a simpler solution.

Comment: Consider adding a testable portion of your data here.

Comment: is there a minimum size of the identity matrices?

Comment: any algorithm must look at all cells in your matrix. imagine there is a non-zero in M_[1, 15625). All of the 'diagonal' matrices disappear, and you are left with but 1 huge, non-decomposable, matrix

Comment: I ended up with a workaround: I look at each diagonal element [i,i] and I use numpy.count_nonzero to determine if it's part of an identity. If it is, I remove that row/column and I store the value of i. In this way I don't end up with the separated blocks, but with a matrix that has all (and only) the non-trivial blocks, which is good enough and I can always recover the whole matrix by inserting the right vectors according the values that I stored.

Comment: sure, if you think this solves your problem then great!